# File downloading corrupted in axios javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to download an excel format file. but after downloading the file getting a corrupted message.
below is my code.

```js
PageModalComponent.prototype.downloadAttachment = function(e) {
    var axios, config, data, payload;
    data = this.fileData[e.currentTarget.dataset.rowIndex];
    payload = {
        downloadRequestDTO: {
            documentID: 136168
        }
    };
    axios = Axios["default"];
    config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: Context.getAuthToken()
        }
    };
    return Axios.get("*******", config).then((function(_this) {
        return function(res) {
            return new Blob([res.data]);
        };
    })(this)).then((function(_this) {
        return function(blob) {
            return _this.fileDownload(blob, "test2324.xlsx");
        };
    })(this))["catch"](function(error) {
        return console.log(error);
    });
    return this;
};

PageModalComponent.prototype.fileDownload = function(blob, documentName) {
    var link, url;
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link = document.createElement('a');
    window.document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.href = url;
    link.download = documentName;
    link.click();
    return setTimeout(function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        return window.document.body.removeChild(link);
    });
};
```

Below are the images which I am getting after downloading.

[image: Excel image]
[image: File corrupted message]

Comment: Does the file opens fine in Excel? Axios is not going to corrupt the file. I'm sure there is a problem with the actual Excel file

Comment: Yes, it opens on excel. after uploading and downloading it is corrupted. if I download the file from postmen it is working.

Comment: The fact that you are getting the message saying there is a problem makes me suspicious. Try creating a new Excel document from scratch, very simple table, and test your code with that instead and see what happens

Comment: I just got one solution instead of AXIOS if we use XMLHttpRequest it is working.

Comment: Great that you got it working! but I'll still have a look into that error message because it may come back later